# OpenCV-python Train-LBPH recognizer

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing a face recognizer in python but I'm in trouble with the  training part.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

data_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/data'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path, f))]


Training_Data, Labels = [],[]


for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
        image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]
        print(image_path)
        images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
        Labels.append(i)

Labels = np.asarray(Labels, dtype=np.int32)

model = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

model.train( np.asarray(Training_Data) ,np.asarray(Labels) )
print("done")
```

When I run it I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Train_Model.py", line 17, in 
>       Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>   TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Thank you.

Comment: make sure `images` are **not** empty before appending them

Answer (score 1):

Add `/` in line number 6 of your code.

```
(data_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/data/')
```

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem , and i solved this.
when you run

```
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path, f))]
```

this command that time add another thumb img at position 0.

so we add new command

```
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path, f))]
onlyfiles = onlyfiles [1:]
```

it means we ignore 1st image

it's running